# How do I set up an email alert when a ssh login is successful?

Tags: bash, ssh

Does anyone have a bash script that will email or notify someone in the case of a successful login to a ssh server?  I want to be notified if anyone logs into my personal box.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 running xfce

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> **Warning:** according to the comments, this does not work if the user creates a file called `~/.ssh/rc`.*

Modify or create `/etc/ssh/sshrc` with the following contents:

```
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip
echo "User $USER just logged in from $ip" | sendemail -q -u "SSH Login" -f "Originator <from@address.com>" -t "Your Name <your.email@domain.com>" -s smtp.server.com &
```

---

This will effectively notify you by email anytime someone logs in through SSH, and the login will be logged in the syslog.

**Note:** You'll need the `sendemail`package (`sudo apt-get install sendemail`) for the email notification to work.

**Note:** works with port forwarding, but with -N option not.

Comment: Does this also work if the client doesn't request a TTY? E.g. `ssh -N` with only port forwarding.

Comment: does this also work when we are using gmail as the smtp server ?

Comment: This needs a **Warning**: This does not work if the user creates a file called `~/.ssh/rc` so it's quite useless as a security measure. @adosaiguas' answer concerning `pam_exec` is the correct one.

Comment: @mchid: If you consider the question *"I want to be notified if anyone logs into my personal box."*, then this *might* be acceptable. *If* you have only one user account. Otherwise you have to do it for *all* accounts, including every newly added account. And ideally you have make sure that users can not modify or delete their `~/.ssh/rc` file. Using a system-wide method based on `pam` is just more reliable and safer, because only `root` can mess with it. So the answer is: The `sshrd` methods works okay for single-user systems, but the `pam` method works reliably for *all* systems.

Comment: It works perfectly.
Just correction, that does not need sendmail:

ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`
logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip
echo "User $USER just logged in from $ip" | mail -s "SSH Login from $ip" your.email@domain.com &

Answer (score 99):

> **Warning:** As always when you change the login configuration, leave a backup ssh session open in the background and test the login from a new terminal.

Since the `sshrc` method doesn't work if the user has their own `~/.ssh/rc` file, I'll explain how to do this with `pam_exec` as @adosaiguas suggested. The good thing is that this can also be easily adapted to login types other than `ssh` (such as local logins or even all logins) by hooking into a different file in `/etc/pam.d/`.

First you need to be able to send mail from the command line. There are other questions about this. On a mail server it's probably easiest to install `mailx` (which is probably already installed anyway). *You need to configure `mailx` so that the user `root` can send mails*.

Then you need an executable script file `login-notify.sh` with the following content. You can change the variables to change the subject and content of the e-mail notification. You can put the file in `/usr/local/bin` or in `/etc/ssh/` for example. Don't forget to run `chmod +x login-notify.sh` to make it executable. And give ownership to root with `sudo chown root:root login-notify.sh`, so that nobody can mess with the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Change these two lines:
sender="sender-address@example.com"
recepient="notify-address@example.org"

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host="`hostname`"
    subject="SSH Login: $PAM_USER from $PAM_RHOST on $host"
    # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
    message="`env`"
    echo "$message" | mailx -r "$sender" -s "$subject" "$recepient"
fi
```

Once you have that, you can add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (with the correct `/path/to/login-notify.sh` of course):

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/login-notify.sh
```

For testing purposes, the module is included as `optional`, so that you can still log in if the execution fails. You could change `optional` to `required`. However, this will prevent any SSH login unless the script is run successfully. Not sure if this is a good idea...

For those of you in need of an explanation of what PAM is and how it works, [here is a very good one](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303034326/http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-pam-works).

Comment: It says: `/etc/ssh/login-notify.sh failed: exit code 13` right after login :(

Comment: Did you make the script executable by running `chmod +x /etc/ssh/login-notify.sh`? Also, can you send mail manually using the `mailx` command used in the script?

Comment: thank you, `chmod` does the trick. Btw I am using sendmail and it works fine too.

Comment: +1 Wonderful. I needed this to 'secure' a server, it worked like a charm !

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Just make sure you have `UsePAM` set to `yes` in your sshd_config.

Comment: You should probably remove the fork (`&`) if you have `required` in the `sshd` file because `mailx` can fail but the user may still have logged on. Also, the script is run as root, so make sure `mailx` is also configured for root

Comment: @texasflood Good point. I'm not even sure anymore, why I wrote the & there in the first place. Probably to reduce the login delay, which might or might not be what you want here.

Comment: Just a note to myself or other people who are new to Selinux. I got a permission error when pam_exec ran the script. Later I found out that it was incorrectly labelled for Selinux. I cloned the script to /bin/ which will automatically be labelled as  `unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0`. Then I  `chmod +x /bin/login-notify.sh` and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for Ubuntu 16.04. Any idea how I can adapt?

Comment: @118218: You should post a separate question with your problem, including error messages, etc.

Comment: /etc/pam.d/login <- for tty logins

Comment: @Fritz the link you provided for PAM is broken :(

Comment: @4wk_ Thanks for the hint. I replaced it with a link to the Internet Archive, so it should work again now.

Comment: From the article > If you find you have trouble remembering the distinction between requisite and required, then join the club! 
I have a mnemonic device: "requisite rhymes with exit"

Comment: Hello - I've set this up on my centos box - but instead of sending an email it posts a message to Microoft teams, however - it appears the rhost is sometimes behind, for example a user ssh'd onto the machine at 8:06, the ip reported was mine, and not his, then at 10:06 i ssh'd onto the machine, and the ip reported was his and not mine - so it's as if the rhost is always one behind, anyone else had this issue?

Comment: FWIW I just used `mail` and that worked just as well.

Comment: @Jags: Did you try to run the script manually, both as the ssh login user, and as root? My guess is that the user running the pam_exec module is not able to access the script.

Comment: @Jags: You can change the permissions to `0700` and owner to `root:root`. This prevents anyone else from executing, reading or editing the script. That's generally a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @fritz Just in case if anyone getting errors with either the script or `mailx` come across this, as texasflood have mentioned, configure `mailx` for root user.

Comment: one-liner (uses a chmod 600 file to store email address): `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nif [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then mail -s "SSH Login: $PAM_USER from $PAM_RHOST on $(hostname)" -r $(cat ~/.env/EMAIL) $(cat ~/.env/EMAIL) <<< "$(date) $(who) $(tail /var/log/auth.log) $(env)"; fi' > /usr/local/bin/notify.sh && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/notify.sh && echo "session    optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/notify.sh" >> /etc/pam.d/sshd` . Also, this page shows an alternate way to use ssh vars without the `~/.ssh/rc warning`: https://wildwolf.name/how-to-log-successful-ssh-login-attempts/

Answer (score 14):

Put the following in `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then 
    TEXT="$(date): ssh login to ${USER}@$(hostname -f)" 
    TEXT="$TEXT from $(echo $SSH_CLIENT|awk '{print $1}')" 
    echo $TEXT|mail -s "ssh login" you@your.domain 
fi
```

#### How the script works

`/etc/profile` is executed at every login (for bash shell users). The if statement will only return true if the user has logged in via ssh, which in turn will cause the indented code block to be run.

Next, we then build the text of the message:

- `$(date)` will be replaced by the output of the `date` command
- `${USER}` will be replaced by the user’s login name
- `$(hostname -f)` will be replaced by the full hostname of the system being logged into

The second `TEXT` line adds to the first, giving the IP address of the system this user is logging in from. Finally, the generated text is sent in an email to your address.

Summary Linux will, by default, record every system login, whether by ssh or not, in the system log files, but sometimes – particularly for a system that is seldom accessed via ssh – a quick and dirty notification can be useful.

Comment: Replaced `hostname -f` with `hostnamectl --static`

Comment: Better put it to /etc/profile.d/ssh_login.sh for example

Comment: easy and concise, I prefer this to @Fritz answer which does not seem to work on Ubuntu 19

Comment: Note that if you use a synchronized email command, user can just ctrl+c and interrupt it before it finishes.

Answer (score 12):

We have been using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor processes on our linux boxes. [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) can also alert by emails on successful logins over ssh. Our [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) config looks like this

```
 check file ssh_logins with path /var/log/auth.log  
     # Ignore login's from whitelist ip addresses
     ignore match "100.100.100.1"    
     # Else, alert
     if match "Accepted publickey" then alert
```

Note: The mailserver configuration, email format etc. should be set in `monitrc` file

**Update:**
Wrote a more detailed [blog post](https://www.elitmus.com/blog/technology/using-monit-to-get-email-alert-on-unauthorized-login/) on this

Answer (score 5):

## Mailgun adaptation of @Fritz answer

After posting I noticed @pacharanero also writes about mailgun, but I don't
understand what they are doing with dig, so I'll post my solution as well.

If you are on a VM that doesn't have SMTP, you might need to use something like mailgun, sendgrid, or the like.  This worked for me on Google Cloud.

One risk of this approach is that an attacker may get your outgoing email sending credentials if they can `sudo su` and find the script or you leave the script for sending email readable.  mailgun has an ip whitelist you should set up, but that's imperfect for this particular use case, obviously.

This script should work with mailgun after you change `mydomain.com` to your actual domain. You could save the script in `/root/login-alert.sh` or some more obscure location.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    APK='api:your-mailgun-api-key-goes-here' 
    FROM='Login Alert <mailgun@mg.mydomain.com>'
    TO='me@mydomain.com'  
    SUBJECT="Login: $PAM_USER @ mydomain.com from $PAM_RHOST"
    DATE=$(date)
    TEXT="At $DATE a login occurred for $PAM_USER on mydomain.com from $PAM_RHOST"
    curl -s --user $APK \
     https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.mydomain.com/messages \
     -F from="$FROM" \
     -F to="$TO" \
     -F subject="$SUBJECT" \
     -F text="$TEXT"
fi
```

After that you can follow @Fritz answer to change `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to include:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /root/login-alert.sh
```

I note this works with no read permissions for arriving users (`chmod 700 /root/login-alert.sh`) so arriving users do not need to have read access to the script.

Answer (score 2):

In this other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/ssh-login-hook) you probably have what you are looking for.
Basically you can add a call to the [mail command](http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/09/25/Ubuntu-Sending-command-line-mail) in the script that is run when a user logs in via ssh: /etc/pam.d/sshd

Answer (score 2):

I've taken some of the excellent answers from this thread and made something that is more-or-less copy-and-pasteable. It uses Mailgun to send the emails so you are spared any issues with setting up STMP. You just need a Mailgun API key and a sending domain.

Upon SSH login, the script will send details of the login (user, hostname, IP address, and all current environment variables) to an email address. It's easy to add other parameters you'd want to send by customising the `message` variable.

```
#!/bin/sh

# this script is triggered on SSH login and sends an email with details of the login
# such as user, IP, hostname, and environment variables

# script should be placed somewhere on the server, eg /etc/ssh
# to trigger on SSH login, put this line in /etc/pam.d/sshd:
#   session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/ssh/snippet-for-sending-emails-on-SSH-login-using-PAM.sh

# Script settings
MAILGUN_API_KEY=
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=
SENDER_NAME=
SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS=
RECIPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS=

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host=$(hostname)
    ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com) # gets public IP
    # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
    subject="SSH login - user:$USER pam-host:$PAM_RHOST host:$host ip:$ip" \
    message=$(env)
    curl -s --user '$MAILGUN_API_KEY' \
        https://api.mailgun.net/v3/$MAILGUN_DOMAIN/messages \
        -F from='$SENDER_NAME <$SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS>' \
        -F to=$RECIPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS \
        -F subject="$subject" \
        -F text="${subject} ${message}"
fi
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.  It is simple and doesn't require sending an e-mail from the machine, which will surely end up in the spam folder unless properly configured.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using *swatchdog* from the *swatch* package to monitor for any lines containing the phrase "*fail*" (case insensitive) in */var/log/auth.log*.  I set it up to run it as a simple systemd service.

```
apt install swatch
```

Create a configure file */etc/swatch/swatch-auth-log.conf* with owner root, permission 644 --

```
watchfor /fail/i
  pipe /usr/local/sbin/sendmail -t auth.log@xxx.com
```

The *"/fail/i"* is a regexp, with the "i" indicating it is case insensitive.  (My *sendmail* is a script sending everything to a fixed address via *mailgun*, so the address doesn't really matter).

Create a *systemd* service file */etc/systemd/system/swatch-auth-log.service* with owner root, permission 644 --

```
[Unit]
Description=monitor /var/log/auth.log, send fail notices by mail

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/swatchdog -c /etc/swatch/swatch-auth-log.conf -t /var/log/auth.log

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=pre-network.target
```

Then enable, start, and view the status of the service --

```
sudo systemctl enable swatch-auth-log.service
sudo systemctl start swatch-auth-log.service
sudo systemctl status swatch-auth-log.service
```

An example of a successful status report --

```
● swatch-auth-log.service - monitor /var/log/auth.log, send fail notices by mail
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/swatch-auth-log.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-01-31 21:41:52 PST; 17min ago
 Main PID: 27945 (swatchdog)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/swatch-auth-log.service
           ├─27945 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/swatchdog -c /etc/swatch/swatch-auth-log.conf -t /var/log/auth.log
           ├─27947 /usr/bin/perl /.swatchdog_script.27945
           └─27949 /usr/bin/tail -n 0 -F /var/log/auth.log

Jan 31 21:41:52 ub18 systemd[1]: Started monitor /var/log/auth.log, send fail notices by mail.
Jan 31 21:41:52 ub18 swatchdog[27945]: *** swatchdog version 3.2.4 (pid:27945) started at Thu Jan 31 21:41:52 PST 2019
```

The service will be automatically started at boot and monitored by *systemd*.

---

**Discussion**

Originally I used a *pam* solution similar to the above, but in */etc/pam.d/common-auth* not *sshd*.  That was to catch ssh, sudo, and logins.  But then after an update all my passwords stopped working, even after changing the passwords in rescue mode.  Eventually I changed the */etc/pam.d/common-auth* back to the original and passwords worked again. Here is a description on the [Stack Exchange UNIX & Linux board](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497980/247579)

I decided it would be safer not to touch difficult to understand security settings.  And everything is in the log files anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just modified @SirCharlo answer

```
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip
echo "User $USER just logged in from $ip" | mail -s "SSH Login" "who to <who-to@youremail.com>" &
```

This works on 14.04, 16.04 and Centos 6.5.x servers I've setup, I'm pretty sure you need to ensure mta is configured, but once that is done, this works a charm. Next step twilio alerts

Answer (score 1):

This script in `/etc/ssh/sshrc` sends an email and adds a log to system logger. A difference is made (so you can disable it if you want) between your personal subnet and the world wide web (requires `sudo apt-get install mailutils`).

```
SUBNET="192.168.0"

IP=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`
CURRENT_SUBNET="$(echo $IP|cut -d'.' -f1-3)"
if [ "$CURRENT_SUBNET" = "$SUBNET" ]; then
        msg="This message comes from same subnet! User $USER just logged in from $IP"
        echo $msg|mail -s "$msg" root
else
        msg="This message comes from different subnet! User $USER just logged in from $IP"
        echo $msg|mail -s "$msg" root
fi

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $IP
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me :

1- Find user folder (root for me) :

```
echo  ~root
```

2- create or edit file ".bashrc" in root folder :

```
nano root/.bashrc
```

(replace "root" with your user folder)

3- add theses lines :

```
# ssh mail notification
echo 'NOTIFICATION - Acces SSH en ROOT sur `hostname` le:' `date` `who` | mail -s "NOTIFICATION - Connexion en ROOT via SSH depuis: `who | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1`" myemail@domain.com
```

Just replace myemail@domain.com by your email.

Repeat with other users if you have more than one.

Source : http://blogmotion.fr/systeme/notification-connexion-ssh-4246

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, but, I had trouble getting mailx to cooperate with my gmail account.
I found an alternative to email. If you have an android phone you can install
"MQTT push Client". Setup an MQTT broker using mosquitto, and publish to it in the login-notify.sh script. Subscribe to the broker+topic with "MQTT push Client" and you're done.
You will get push notifications on your phone, no email needed.