# How to include the authorized key used in an ssh login notification email - Ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh

I followed this: [How do I set up an email alert when a ssh login is successful?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful)
to get email notification sent to me whenever someone logs in with ssh.
But I would like to include the name / comment ssh authorized key that was used:

```
`login as: <myuser>
Authenticating with public key "STEVEN-rsa-key-20180820" from agent Linux genius`
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/can-i-find-out-which-ssh-key-was-used-to-access-an-account