# Cant send mail when ssh login succesfull through pam_exec

Tags: 20.04

Noob ubuntu user here, I want to send an email on succesfull ssh login on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS machine, I got the idea from this other thread:

[How do I set up an email alert when a ssh login is successful?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful)

I edited /etc/pam.d/sshd file and added the last line

/etc/pam.d/sshd

```
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/sendmail.sh
```

And my sendmail script (changed key and mail for privacy reasons):

/usr/local/bin/sendmail.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
##This script sends a message

if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host="'ubuntu-server'"
    subject="SSH Login: $PAM_USER from $PAM_RHOST on $host"
    curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.com/messages -F from='Server Notification <postmaster@mydomain.com>' -F to='mymail@gmail.com' -F subject="$subject" -F text='Detected succesfull SSH login'
fi

exit 0;
```

Is there something I missed? do I have to restart pam or something?

Where can I see error logs if they exist?