# SSH - How to force execution of a script ( /etc/sshrc , ForceCommand, .. ? ) on login but still allow execution of the client's ~/.ssh/rc?

Tags: server, ssh, scripts

As far as i know upon SSH login the following files are executed

```
[SERVER] /etc/environment

[Client] ~/.ssh/environment
-> can be locally overriden by "SSH_ENV" environment variable
-> will override Host=>SendEnv in local ~/.ssh/config
-> will be filtered by "AcceptEnv" directive(s) in remote /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-> will NOT be used if "PermitUserEnvironment no" in remote /etc/ssh/sshd_config

[SERVER] /etc/ssh/sshrc         
-> will NOT get executed if "ForceCommand" exists in remote /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-> will NOT get executed if local ~/.ssh/rc exists
-> can be overriden by "ForceCommand" (kind of)

[Client] ~/.ssh/rc              
-> will NOT get executed if "ForceCommand" is configured
-> can be overriden by local "???" environment variable?
```

## Question

How can i force the execution of a script on the server but still allow the client to use his `~/.ssh/rc` ?

**Bonus question**

Is it possible to override the local `~/.ssh/rc` location using an environment variable? If yes which one?

Comment: What are you trying to do with ~/.ssh/rc ? If you are going to force a command, perhaps call a script (from the corced command) and source ~/ssh/rc from the script.

Comment: i can't source the client's `~/.ssh/rc` from inside a remotely executed command, can i ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems to be to evaluate the

> SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

environment variable that gets set to the command in the client's `~/.ssh/rc` inside the script configured as [ForceCommand](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5#ForceCommand).

I found this possible solution in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/10371/216975).

---

**Remaining**: Is there a way to override the `~/.ssh/rc` location using an environment variable?