# Run a script as root after ssh login with any user

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, root, log

I am trying to create a custom log file that logs all ssh connections in a specific format. However, **I need the log file to only be writtable and readable by root.** So, the script needs to be run with root. This is my script :

```
now=$(date)
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

echo "User $USER just logged in from $ip at [$now]" >> /home/user/ssh_log.txt
```

Now, I run the script in `/etc/ssh/sshrc`, but this file only executes as the user and not root. Is there a way to execute the script as root when a user ssh in the server?

Comment: What if you were simply to monitor your existing logs and extract the information you want? `sshd` is already logging the username, the origin ip address, and the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run scripts automatically in server after ssh connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397674/run-scripts-automatically-in-server-after-ssh-connection) or perhaps https://superuser.com/questions/355029/how-to-automatically-run-commands-on-ssh-login

Comment: I need the script to be run as root

Comment: Why can you not extract the required information from `/var/log/auth.log`? The information is there.

Comment: Well if it's the only possible solution well I think I'll use it but it would be great if my custom log would work